# string interpolation does not work in the Angular templates

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I want to display a default image when the hotel does not have image. Here is my code:

hotel.component.html :

```
<img [src]="hotel.image!='' ? '{{cdn}}/{{hotel.image}}.jpg' : '{{cdn}}/images/no-image.png'">
```

hotel.component.ts :

```
...
export class HotelsComponent {
  hotel!: HotelViewModel;
  cdn!:string;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.cdn='http://cdn.example.com';
  }
 }
```

and the output is

```
<img src="{{cdn}}/images/no-image.png">
```

But I want

```
<img src="http://cdn.example.com/images/no-image.png">
```

Comment: You are using property binding with `[src]=` which cannot be combined with string interpolation `{{cdn}}`

Answer (score 2):

You dont need to use string interpolation (`{{}}`) within property bindings

you can directly use the property values in the binding expression. To display a default image when the hotel doesn't have an image

```
<img [src]="hotel.image !== '' ? cdn + '/' + hotel.image + '.jpg' : cdn + '/images/no-image.png'">
```